# Change background on applicationbar when light theme is on

Tags: c#, background, windows-phone-8, themes

Hi i have this problem with my applicationbar.
When i change the theme to light the icons turns to black, can I prevent this or can I
change the backgroundcolor to something else when light theme is on.

Now i have a purple background all the time so either change the icons or background.

Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Detect the Dark or Light theme color, you can use

```
bool DarkThemeUsed ()
{ 
     return Visibility.Visible ==   (Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"];
}

bool LightThemeUsed() 
{
     return Visibility.Visible == (Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"];
}
```

Source is [developer.nokia.com](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Theme_aware_Windows_Phone_application): On this website, you've many idea and solution for little problem on windows phone :D

You can just test if your phone use the dark or the light them just when you started your application ( on your App.xaml.cs):

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    DetectUserTheme();
}

private void DetectUserTheme()
{
    if(LightThemeUsed())
    {
        // Adapt your icons, background for the light theme.
        return;
    }

    // Adapt your icons, background for the dark theme. 
}
```

You can also use the color accent, define by the user :

```
 Color currentAccentColorHex = 
        (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
```

And you can use it in your application for few color text or element...

Comment: Does this work if its a custom made toolkit for the datepickerpage for example?, When do i fire this code? in the startup?

Comment: Replace, in the code 'if(LightThemeUsed)' by 'if(LightThemeUsed())'. I've just edit my mistake.

Comment: Now i have no error. But am I thinking wrong here if i but this inside  if statment for **LightThemeUsed**? 

**var AppBarSetting = new ApplicationBar();
               AppBarSetting.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(0,255,255,255);**

Comment: I dont know why i didnt see this but the applicationbar has a foregroundColor that i can set and dont need to check it when launching but this help is really good anyway.